# Subprocess with a variable that contains a whitespace (path)

Tags: python, subprocess, removing-whitespace

Just started Python again and now I'm already stuck on the following...

I'm trying to use subprocess.Popen with a variable with a whitespace in it (a Windows path).

Doing a print on the variable the variable seems to work fine. But when using the variable in `subprocess.Popen`, the variable is cut off by the first whitespace.

Below a part of the script (the variable 'image_file' contains the Windows Path(s) with spaces)

```
def start_phone(image_file):
    cmd = tar_exe + " -tf "+ image_file
    print (cmd)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

How can I use subprocess with a variable with whitespaces (path) in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either put double quotes around each argument with potential white spaces in it:

```
cmd = f'"{tar_exe}" -tf "{image_file}"'
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

or don't use `shell=True` and instead put arguments in a list:

```
subprocess.Popen([tar_exe, '-tf', image_file])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) you'll see that arguments must be provided to subprocess commands in the form of a list, so your code sample should look like

```
def start_phone(image_file):
    subprocess.Popen([tar_exe, "-tf", image_file])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [shlex.quote()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) for handling the whitespaces for `subprocess.Popen()`. This must be used with `shell=False` for avoiding any command injection which is a possibility.

Comment: It works only on linux